# Por que especificar uma quantidade de asserções de modo explícito no meu teste?

Tags: javascript, testes, testes-de-unidade, jest

Comecei a estudar testes unitários com Jest, mas não entendi muito bem o uso de `expect.assertions` ao realizar testes com JavaScript. Vamos considerar o exemplo abaixo dado pela própria documentação do Jest:

```
test('the fetch fails with an error', () => {
  expect.assertions(1);
  return fetchData().catch(e => expect(e).toMatch('error'));
});
```

Nesse caso, estamos testando uma função chamada `fetchData()` e esperamos um único retorno em que devolve uma string `error` (ou seja, a promise cai no `reject`). Então, o uso de `assertions` é somente para afirmar para o Jest que é só esse resultado que nos interessa, fazendo com que qualquer outro retorno da Promise seja dado como erro no teste? Por exemplo, caso a Promise seja resolvida, o teste precisa acusar erro, já que esperamos somente um resultado, que é algo com a string `error`. É isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, a ideia é quase essa mesmo (explicarei no final uma observação sobre a afirmação da pergunta).

No caso, como você está testando um erro, que pode *não* ocorrer (por algum erro), é importante que você diga para o seu framework de testes — como o Jest, nesse caso — quantas asserções estão sendo realizadas. Para isso, alguma API como o [`expect.assertions`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectassertionsnumber) no Jest deve ser utilizada.

Assim, caso o número de asserções seja diferente do número que você forneceu, o teste dará erro e você saberá que tem algo errado.

Esse tipo de asserção garante a integridade do seu teste, que está, de fato, testando o comportamento do seu código.

No entanto, não é necessário sempre informar o número de asserções a serem feitas dentro de um bloco de testes, já que, geralmente, quando você testar algo errado, um erro será lançado pelo próprio comportamento normal da linguagem (como um [`TypeError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError) no JavaScript ao tentar invocar um método que não foi corretamente implementado em um objeto).

Nesse caso, como nenhum erro de sintaxe ou algum outro reconhecível pelo próprio framework de testes ou linguagem, você precisa informar explicitamente que você espera um comportamento. Assim, caso o comportamento não ocorrer, você terá uma asserção que não foi executada e saberá disso. Sem esse número explícito, passaria batido.

> […] Então, o uso de assertions é somente para afirmar para o Jest que é só esse resultado que nos interessa, fazendo **com que qualquer outro retorno da Promise seja dado como erro no teste**? Por exemplo, caso a Promise seja resolvida, o teste precisa acusar erro, já que esperamos somente um resultado, que é algo com a string error. […]

Não creio que o destacado acima esteja correto, uma vez que o objetivo de definir o número explícito de asserções não é garantir um comportamento específico, mas sim garantir que uma quantidade N de asserções sejam executadas.

Como já vimos acima, se uma asserção não for executada, o framework de testes não terá como saber se algo ocorreu de fato (já que um erro, por exemplo, pode não ter sido lançado). Desse modo, tendo em vista que o fato de uma asserção não ser executada *não* falhará o teste, precisamos explicitar a quantidade de asserções que devem ser feitas no caso de uma delas estiver em um trecho de código que *pode* não ser executado no caso de algum comportamento incorreto.

Comment: Olá, Luiz Felipe. Então o uso de `assertion` é para informar quantas vezes eu espero por um determinado comportamento? No caso do exemplo da doc eu informo que espero que um erro seja retornado com a string 'error' uma única vez. E se informasse um `expect.assertions(2);` nesse mesmo código? Estaria dizendo para o Jest que espero aquele retorno duas vezes?

Comment: Sim, mas não se limita a isso, você está dizendo que dentro daquele bloco de testes duas asserções devem ser feitas, não importa onde.